# Will Open Collector Output of 0~12V damage 0~5V input DAQ?

Tags: voltage, voltage-measurement, datalogger

In my lab configuration, I am using open-collector with 2K Ohm pull-up resistor to 12V.

The data aquisition card I am using is from national instrument.

If I look at the Low and High voltage of open collector output when not connected to input of DAQ, i get 0.2 ~ 12V.

However, If I connect to the input of DAQ, the voltage becomes 0.2~5.6V.

Will DAQ input be safe from over voltage since 12V is not directly connected to the input, but through 2K Ohm resistor?

Comment: Why not add a voltage divider?

Comment: @Passerby Very good simple answer. If you would, please write it as answer, so that I can  select your answer.

Comment: Well. I provided a solution to your problem, not an answer to your question, which is also a valid concern.

Comment: `The data aquisition card I am using is from national instrument.`, if you give an actual _model_ maybe you'll get better answers. It involves maximum current through protection diodes etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ESD diodes are designed to be small and fast but are limited to 5mA DC

Thus 7V above 5V into 5k may draw 1.4mA which meets this criteria.

However 12V must never be applied before 5V to avoid SCR latchup, thus an R divider is safer.